# jquery chosen dropdownlistfor issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using jquery chosen for dropdownlistfor and it works perfectly fine. i have placed a logic in jquery when there is change in selection it automatically checks all the added elements. but when i try to delete certain element, it does not allow me to delete it in-fact it gets stuck. If i comment the jquery script which i created it works fine. i assume there is issue in jquery script.

**View**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Mechanism.Controls, listofControls, new { @class = "chosen-select", @style = "width:350px", multiple = "multiple", @id="cmbcontrols"  })

<script>

$(document).on('change', '#cmbcontrols', function () {

    var dropdown = $("#cmbcontrols").val();
    var isTrue = false;

    var selectedOptions = dropdown.toString().split(',');

    for (var i in selectedOptions) {
        if (selectedOptions[i] == 2) {
            isTrue = true;
        }

        i++;
    }

    if (isTrue) {
        //sms mode is selected            
        $('#txtvalueselector').show();
        $('#lblvalueselector').show();
    }
    else {
        //dial mode is selected
        $('#txtvalueselector').hide();
        $('#lblvalueselector').hide();
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: first problem is with your  for (var i in selectedOptions) {if (selectedOptions[i] == 2)

Comment: @h,,ad:  please mark the answer as helpful if issue resolved by this

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with for loop i guess, you are getting item in i but treating it as index of array. Try this code

```
  $.each(selectedOptions,function(i,obj) {
        if (obj == 2) {
            isTrue = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
```